# I need an example for extracting the info from a SqlLite3 database with TikaOnDotNet, do you have one?

Tags: c#, sqlite, apache-tika

I used TikaOnDotNet library in order to extract the content info from files and index the info with Lucene, but I have a problem by extracting the data from sqllite3 file: the data is not extracted and the tika parser automatically identifies the EmptyParser. Do you know if I can specify the parser or why it does not work? Also is there an option to pass some custom handler to TikaOnDotNet or to obtain the  content info not as string but as a list of rows?

Comment: SQLite needs an additional native library, did you add that to your classpath?

Comment: I use TikaOnDotNet that has the JDBC library dll added as a reference, how could I check if this is enough or not?